# Adding 2 separate scrollers in mobiscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobiscroll

I'm trying to add separate scrollers for date and time pickers with mobiscroll but for some reason i can only get the first scroller to work.

HTML:

```
<div id="set_call_div">
        <label>
            <span>Date:</span>
            <input id="date_scroller" name="date">
        </label>
         <br>
        <label>
            <span>Time:</span>
            <input id="time_scroller" name="time">
        </label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date_scroller").mobiscroll().date();
    $("#time_scroller").mobiscroll().time();

});
```

The first one responds and opens, The second one doesn't respond at all.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly how it is supposed to be initialized, and it should be working...

1. Check the console for JS errors.
2. Try a simple page holding just the two textboxes and minimal scripts for init